# Daily motion get iframe video

Tags: iframe, dailymotion-api

Is it possible to get player and use its api from the iframe which is already in the page?

```
 <iframe id="dir" src="http://www.dailymotion.com/embed/video/xx9c3g?api=1" width="640" height="360" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

Their docs describe how to create player, but I cant find an example how to use if iframe is already in the page:

https://developer.dailymotion.com/player/#embed-sdk-js-how-to

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the question, unfortunately, this functionality is not available and we recommend integrating with our JS SDK which provides easy access to our Player API.